# TMUX displays data in a chaotic view

Tags: tmux

I was running one command in my tmux session on one of the tabs when I decided to interrupt it.
After I stopped it, the data in my tab started to display in a chaotic view. Only in this tab.

1. The command I ran was the custom one - I was running the script and stopped it by pressing `ctrl + C`
2. Then I tried

```
 echo ^v^o
 reset
 printf "\033c"
```

How I can solve the issue, please?

[Screenshot with the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HuqEp.png)

Comment: I added some clarifications

Answer (score 0):

You can do `C-b : send -R` (that is, enter `send -R` at the tmux command prompt) to ask tmux to reset the pane state.

Comment: No  reaction from the tmux on this command